# Why Benchmarking lookups for vector vs unordered_map yields inconsistent results in each run?

Tags: c++, hashmap

I encountered a similar problem like this question : [Timed vector vs map vs unordered_map lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871315/timed-vector-vs-map-vs-unordered-map-lookup)

But my case only on `vector` vs `unordered_map` on a small scale of elements(0-100, mostly will be 0-20). So I changed the author @gitgregor code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

unsigned dummy = 0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> v;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned> u;

    unsigned elementCount = 1;

    struct Times
    {
        unsigned long long v;
        unsigned long long u;
    };
    std::map<unsigned, Times> timesMap;

    while (elementCount != 100)
    {
        v.clear();
        u.clear();

        elementCount *= 10;
        std::vector<unsigned int> tmp;
        tmp.reserve(elementCount);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < elementCount; ++i)
        {
            tmp.push_back(std::rand()%50000);
        }
        // fill vector and unmap with random numbers
        for (const auto integer : tmp)
        {
            v.emplace_back(integer);
            u.insert(std::make_pair(integer, 1));
        }
        // fill a testset with 10000 random numbers to test lookup
        std::vector<unsigned> tmp2;
        tmp2.reserve(10000);
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp2.size(); i++)
        {
            tmp2.push_back(std::rand()%50000);
        }

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto integer : tmp2)
        {
            auto findItr = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), integer);
            if (findItr != v.end())
            {
                dummy++;
            }
        }
        auto tp0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        unsigned long long vTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp0).count();

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto integer : tmp2)
        {
            const bool res = u[integer] == 0;
            if (res)
            {
                dummy++;
            }
        }
        auto tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        unsigned long long uTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp1).count();

        timesMap.insert(std::make_pair(elementCount, Times{ vTime, uTime }));
    }

    for (auto& itr : timesMap)
    {
        std::cout << "Element count: " << itr.first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::vector time:        " << itr.second.v << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::unordered_map time: " << itr.second.u << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << dummy;
}
```

I turned off optimization and have random numbers to fill `vector` and `unordered_map`, and use a number set of 10000 random numbers to test lookup. But the results are not consistent at all:

```
First run:
Element count: 10
std::vector time:        100
std::unordered_map time: 100
-----------------------------------
Element count: 100
std::vector time:        0
std::unordered_map time: 100
-----------------------------------

Second Run:
Element count: 10
std::vector time:        200
std::unordered_map time: 200
-----------------------------------
Element count: 100
std::vector time:        100
std::unordered_map time: 100
-----------------------------------

Third Run:
Element count: 10
std::vector time:        100
std::unordered_map time: 0
-----------------------------------
Element count: 100
std::vector time:        100
std::unordered_map time: 0
-----------------------------------
```

And the results look also strange with only numbers : 0, 100 and 200.

Does anyone have some idea why?

Comment: There are several reasons for such results. First all time measurements should do very many operations, you run N times similar operation and one for total time T one operation time will be T/N. So T should be equal to 1-3 seconds to make precise measurements. Second, all measured structures and variables should be marked `volatile`, because non-volatile variables are optimized by compiler and often all code removed (code becomes empty) if it doesn't make any side effect. To have running time T to be 1-3 seconds you have to run many Millions of operations not just 100!

Comment: @Arty there is side effect in this code and using `volatile` will defeat the purpose of testing - you should test optimized code, not artificially degraded,

Comment: @Slava If there is side effect then the reason of bad results is probably due to running to few iterations. Adding element to unordered_map or vector takes nonseconds. So you have to run dozens of millions of iterations to get precise result.

Comment: @Arty I agree with the that part, I disagree with using `volatile`

Comment: @Slava but I turned off optimization for testing. Because I saw the `std::find` is optimized away in optimized code. Altough I use random numbers to test. So it becomes unclear for me if the optimization should stay or not.

Comment: @Arty thanks a lot! i thought 10000 is engouh. I will use much more iterations

Comment: @Dexter "but I turned off optimization for testing" rule N1 - never benchmark unoptimized build. We may end here.

Comment: @Slava volatile should be used for side effect, probably I was incorrect by saying that everything should be made volatile. One should make volatile just one tiny variable with final result. Final result can be just number of elements (`.size()`) of structure after inserting into structure some set of elements. This will ensure side effect. Or another way to side effect is to print first elements of structure to std::cout.

Comment: @Arty `dummy` is used and output to `std::cout`, looks side effect all right for me. OP says he disabled optimization, we can stop discussion here.

Comment: @Slava but in the linked post, the answer said: "Second, according to your times, your vector exhibits linear time, which is something that just can't be, as complexity is O(N*N) in your algorithm. Probably it WAS optimized away. Instead of trying to combat optimization, I would suggest just turning it off."

Comment: That is actively bad advice, thanks for pointing it out, we will downvote that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the real reason for your code not measuring correctly, because you had loop `for (int i = 0; i < tmp2.size(); i++)` which runs 0 times, because size of tmp2 is 0 at start. Hence you were testing against 0 integers from tmp2, hence you had almost 0 time (no operations made).

I modified your code to fix issue above, also fix some compilation issues, also set number of integers (iterations) to 1 million instead of 10 thousand, also I computed average running time (in nano seconds) instead of total time, also added std::map measurement in case you want to chooe it. Down below is full corrected code.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/rsvGTG)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

volatile size_t dummy_total = 0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> v;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned> u;
    std::map<unsigned, unsigned> m;

    unsigned elementCount = 5;

    struct Times
    {
        double v = 0;
        double m = 0;
        double u = 0;
    };
    std::map<unsigned, Times> timesMap;

    while (elementCount <= 80)
    {
        size_t dummy = 0;
        v.clear();
        u.clear();
        m.clear();

        elementCount *= 2;
        std::vector<unsigned int> tmp;
        tmp.reserve(elementCount);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < elementCount; ++i)
        {
            tmp.push_back(std::rand()%50000);
        }
        // fill vector and unmap with random numbers
        for (const auto integer : tmp)
        {
            v.emplace_back(integer);
            u.insert(std::make_pair(integer, 1));
            m.insert(std::make_pair(integer, 1));
        }
        // fill a testset with 10000 random numbers to test lookup
        std::vector<unsigned> tmp2(1000000);
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp2.size(); i++)
        {
            tmp2[i] = std::rand()%50000; 
        }

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto integer : tmp2)
        {
            auto findItr = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), integer);
            if (findItr != v.end())
            {
                ++dummy;
            }
        }
        auto tp0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        double vTime = double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp0).count()) / tmp2.size();

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto integer : tmp2)
        {
            const bool res = u.count(integer) != 0;
            if (res)
            {
                ++dummy;
            }
        }
        auto tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        double uTime = double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp1).count()) / tmp2.size();

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto integer : tmp2)
        {
            const bool res = m.count(integer) != 0;
            if (res)
            { 
                ++dummy;
            }
        }
        auto tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        double mTime = double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp2).count()) / tmp2.size();

        dummy_total = dummy_total + dummy;
        timesMap.insert(std::make_pair(elementCount, Times{ vTime, mTime, uTime }));
    }

    for (auto& itr : timesMap)
    {
        std::cout << "Element count: " << itr.first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::vector time:        " << itr.second.v << " ns" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::map time: " << itr.second.m << " ns" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::unordered_map time: " << itr.second.u << " ns" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << dummy_total;
}
```

Output:

```
Element count: 10
std::vector time:        12.8182 ns
std::map time: 26.4334 ns
std::unordered_map time: 10.2652 ns
-----------------------------------
Element count: 20
std::vector time:        24.1431 ns
std::map time: 33.9809 ns
std::unordered_map time: 13.0953 ns
-----------------------------------
Element count: 40
std::vector time:        60.7386 ns
std::map time: 42.3911 ns
std::unordered_map time: 20.1641 ns
-----------------------------------
Element count: 80
std::vector time:        102.167 ns
std::map time: 52.1565 ns
std::unordered_map time: 10.2345 ns
-----------------------------------
Element count: 160
std::vector time:        190.878 ns
std::map time: 68.7916 ns
std::unordered_map time: 13.5962 ns
-----------------------------------
18726
```

Comment: nice catch! but why is `dummy_total` 40022173? isn't it supposed to be 40000000?

Comment: @Dexter No, first of all dummy total doesn't count all elements, it counts only part of them, those that matched special condition. Second thing is that instead of your dummy variable I put dummy total which is sum of all dummies.

Comment: you are right. but isn't the upper limit for `dummy_total` to be 4 * 10000000 (four times iteration)? if all conditions met

Comment: @Dexter I fixed that bug with dummy the way you like, look at modified code and output above! Now it is upper limited by what you wanted. Also I found one more bug in your code, very nasty, basically your code was doing `u[integer]` which creates new element inside hash map instead of just searching. I modified it to use `u.count(integer)` which does just search!

Comment: @Dexter Now dummy_total shows exactly number of found elements (not all!)! Which is quite small, around 60000.

Comment: @Dexter BTW, as you see `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is used to measure time. Its resolution (minimal measured time) on Windows is around 1 mcs (micro second) and on linux usually around 50 ns (nano seconds). So in cross-platform code you have to do only measurements that take at least dozens of micro seconds in order to be precise. It means if each operation time is around 10-20 ns then you have to make not less than 1000-5000 such operations. But if you run much more operations than results will be better, i.e. if you can afford waiting 1-2 seconds then always run 10-100 million ops

Comment: @Dexter BTW, if you really need very high performant unordered map operations then you can use [xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) library. It is fastest hash that I ever saw that is collision resistant. It is faster then memory copying (`memcpy()`). If you're interested in using such optimization for hash map then tell me, I'll write a code snippet for you to use and test this lib. Maybe I'm wrong, maybe for small integer keys it is not that very important to use xxhash. But for keys of size above 100 bytes definitely xxhash will be a great win.

Comment: thanks for all the help! I will take a look at that, but for the current state I will only need to choose between `vector` and `unordered_map` for integer as key(pid, to be more precise), and the cache is most likely to be small(0 ~ 20). So I think vector might be faster in this case. But of course I will have to benchmark `insert` and `delete` too.

Comment: @Dexter Also you may want to test also std::map. Because usually statistics for elements search is next - 1) std::vector is best for 0-10 elements. 2) std::map is best for 10-100 elements. 3) std::unordered_map is best for 100 and more elements.    So for your range maybe std::map will be best, just try. Time complexities for them are next - 1) std::vector O(N) 2) std::map O(log2(N)) 3) std::unordered_map O(1).   Although std::unordered_map has O(1) time, it has large constant inside O(1), thats why unordered map only the best choice for quite large N, around >100.

Comment: @Dexter Just added std::map measurement to code in my answer if you'll decide to choose it. Looks like std::map is not that good as I thought, unordered map is still better choice for more than 10 elements.